# React.js: Why i cant see HTML content on the browser?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

I started to learn React, i am writing my code on VS Studio. Can someone tell me why i cant see the HTML code on the browser?

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx1OH.jpg)

Comment: Did you create your project with npx create-react-app or yarn create react-app? And are you running the start script? There's no indication of what you are trying to do to see the result in the browser.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, the information you gave is not enough. Can we see your `index.html` file for example? Also, please do not share your code as images. Just copy and paste them into code blocks in your question. As other people commented how do you start your application? What do you see in the dev console?

Comment: Does your index.html have a `<div id="root"></div>` to link your component to? Have you imported your component correctly? Have you tried starting your project by opening console on your root and running `npm start`?

Comment: @CalIrvine yes i created it with npx create-react-app. I ran 'npm start' but all i can see on the browser is blue screen and this line 'Edit src/App.js and save to reload'.
@devserkan Thank you for tips. My HTML:
  `</head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
`
There is nothing in my console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are editing an index.js in the root directory of your project, but with create-react-app the index.js you should be editing is in your src folder. Edit the correct index.js file and your changes should show on the browser.

Comment: This answer is based on the image you posted showing the path of the index.js and the information that you provided about how you set up the project, and what you are seeing.  'Edit src/App.js and save to reload' is the placeholder in create-react-app.

Comment: this! yes! Thank you so much. This is why i uploaded an image, so you can see the path. Thank you and have a nice day you all.